# Creating a column from a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

So what i'm trying to do left join this table that would define what a question is from the questions table and check with the responses table.
I wrote the left join to define each question as its own column but its not working.. any ideas?

```
select *
FROM Leads l
/*JOIN Projects P ON L.projectid=P.projectid
JOIN Leads LE ON LE.LISTID=L.listid
JOIN Calls CA ON CA.LEADID=LE.leadid*/

join Lists li on (li.Listid=l.Listid)
JOIN Projects P ON (Li.projectid=P.projectid)
join Calls ca on (ca.leadid=l.leadid)

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
leadid,
Authorized=MIN(CASE qname WHEN  'Authorized' THEN RESPONSE END),
ReplacementName=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'ReplacementName' THEN RESPONSE END),
SpokeToGroup=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToGroup' THEN RESPONSE END),
SpokeToName=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToName' THEN RESPONSE END),
SpokeToTitle=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToTitle' THEN RESPONSE END),
WishToRecieve=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'WishToRecieve' THEN RESPONSE END),
Question01=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'Question01' THEN RESPONSE END),
... -- lots of other fields
MAGExpiration=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'MAGExpiration' THEN RESPONSE END),
SourceGroup=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SourceGroup' THEN RESPONSE END),
SourceID=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SourceID' THEN RESPONSE END),
ClientOtherID=MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'ClientOtherID' THEN RESPONSE END)

from Questions q join Responses r on (r.questionid=q.questionid)
)
```

Comment: If you have columns called something like "Foo1", Foo2", etc, this is usually a sign that your database is not correctly normalized. Questions should be in their own table.

Comment: Are you running this query in MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subquery missing a `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY leadid
```

You are using all of the aggregate functions but you are not grouping by anything.

You should also include an `ELSE` on your `CASE` statements.

There might be better ways for you to perform this.  If you are using SQL Server, then you can perform this much easier using the `PIVOT` function. Since you have so many fields that you are attempting to pivot, you should look at using dynamic SQL in sql server and prepared statements in MySQL.

Edit #1, you also appear to be missing a few key items:

```
select *
FROM Leads l
/*JOIN Projects P ON L.projectid=P.projectid
JOIN Leads LE ON LE.LISTID=L.listid
JOIN Calls CA ON CA.LEADID=LE.leadid*/

join Lists li on (li.Listid=l.Listid)
JOIN Projects P ON (Li.projectid=P.projectid)
join Calls ca on (ca.leadid=l.leadid)
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    leadid,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN  'Authorized' THEN RESPONSE END) as Authorized,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'ReplacementName' THEN RESPONSE END) as ReplacementName,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToGroup' THEN RESPONSE END) as SpokeToGroup,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToName' THEN RESPONSE END) as SpokeToName,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SpokeToTitle' THEN RESPONSE END) as SpokeToTitle,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'WishToRecieve' THEN RESPONSE END) as WishToRecieve,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'Question01' THEN RESPONSE END) as Question01,
    ... -- lots of other fields
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'MAGExpiration' THEN RESPONSE END) as MAGExpiration,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SourceGroup' THEN RESPONSE END) as SourceGroup,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'SourceID' THEN RESPONSE END) as SourceID,
    MIN(CASE qname WHEN 'ClientOtherID' THEN RESPONSE END) as ClientOtherID
  from Questions q 
  join Responses r 
    on (r.questionid=q.questionid)
  group by leadid
) qr  -- an alias for the subquery
  on l.leadid = qr.leadid  -- the on for the join
```

Comment: Okay well that didn't help to much.. I'm running this in mysql on my MSSQL server the left join subquery runs fine is there any major  changes from mssql to mysql?

Comment: @user1922240 are you getting an error?  Can you clarify what doesn't work?

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 419   and 419 is just the group by there is no ''

Comment: Okay now it's saying [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'Authorized' in 'field list' the thing is i'm doing that query to define each row from the question's field as a column in my mssql server this works fine but let me check my table structure in my mssql server really fast.

Comment: @user1922240 see my edit, change the way you are giving aliases to your columns in the subquery

Comment: That works thank you so much there are a ton of columns to do it to. But i tested it on 3 and its running. Once again thankyou